# My extension requires PHP extension

Tags: module

I developed my own extension but in order for it to work it requires the PHP JSON extension. How can I specify that requirement for module installation? Do I have to mention it in the composer.json?
And what about Magento 1?

Comment: Magento 1 or Magento 2 extension?

Comment: I need solutions for both Magento versions.